# Normal convergence of a complex serie

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's $u_n(z) = \frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{5^n z^{n+1}}$ with z complex. If r1 and r2 are roots of $z^2-3z+1=0$ and if $r1 < r < r2$ then prove that $\sum_{n\geq 0} u_n (r e^{it})$ converges normally on $[0, 2\pi]$.

I really don't know how to start this problem and I can't see where $z^2-3z+1=0$  is coming from. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One just uses the usual estimates on power series convergence, that is $u_n(z)$ by comparing it with power series, that is by checking when upper limit of $nth$ root of $|u_{n}(z)|$ is less than 1. It is easy to see that this limit is not bigger than $\frac{(1+|z|)^2}{5|z|}$. So the question is for what real x we have $\frac{(1+x)^2}{5x} < 1$ Simplifying, you get $x^2-3x+1 < 0$.  Now, note that the equation has two real and positive roots (since its value at 1 is negative) and its leading coefficient is positive so it is indeed negative between roots.